# Access denied on create any workflow on Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, access-denied

When I change the mode of start of any workflow in any List of the SharePoint 2013, I receive a Access Denied message, but I have full control of site.
I also receive message "Error on configuration file".
And all workflows of the site are stopping automatic
How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

Workflow 2013 can't work with permission for groups, somelly individually

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Can you clarify?